# iOS - Continuous Integration with Jenkins / Fastlane

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration, fastlane

I'm setting up a continuous integration server on AWS EC2, and wanted to integrate [Fastlane](https://docs.fastlane.tools/) into it.  Per the Fastlane docs:

`fastlane requires macOS or Linux with Ruby 2.0.0 or above`

and also

`Deploying from your own computer isn't cool. You know what's cool? Letting a remote server publish app updates for you.`  [link](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/docs/Jenkins.md)

My question is, if your continuous integration server is a Linux box (which it most certainly will be), then how can you do remote builds for an iOS app -- which Fastlane seems to suggest that you do -- on your Linux box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use a Linux machine for an iOS app as you need Xcode to build it.

You can use online ci servers such as https://travis-ci.org/ or https://www.bitrise.io/.

Comment: Ah alright.  Somewhat unfortunate, but I guess I've come to expect that with Apple :) Thanks for the info!

Comment: This is partially false..If you want to use Linux machine to build your iOS Apps.Make sure you make distributed builds by creating a slave(mac ) that provides apple environment. Jenkins does provide master slave configuration

Comment: @ThatlazyiOSGuy웃 Can I use successfully Jenkins Master (ubuntu ec2 instance) and mac os (Laptop) as Jenkins slave node along with Fastlane and jenkins xcode plugin ? Did it worked for you ? I am getting issues

Comment: @AshishKarpe Yes... it worked. Few times the connection between slave and master was disconnected.

Comment: @ThatlazyiOSGuy웃  I have issues in provisioning profiles ! I am able to build and create ipa using xcode in Laptop manually but it's giving issues when I try using Jenkins (Master-ubuntu ec2 instance)